# keyboard remapping - dell latitude 5511

Tags: windows, mapping, keyboard-layout

My office/work notebook has a weird keyboard:

- the HOME, END and Print Screen keys are COMBINED with F10, F11 and F12, respectively (so I need to press the Fn key to make them work)
- there are some buttons for (the Windows) calculator: < launch the calculator >, CE (I believe it has something to do with clearing memory), +/- (changing signs of a number) and <- (I'm clueless and not interested)

I know there is a BIOS option for selecting the behaviour of the F-keys (as device controlling key, i.e. sound level change, back-light, screen luminosity, etc., OR as normal F-keys (F1 - help, F2 rename, etc) and I selected to have the normal F-key behaviour (and I would stick with this), but I cannot UN-COUPLE F10, F11, F12 from Print Screen, Home, End.

Is there an application which lets me remap these calculator buttons into Home, End, Print Screen and [Windows Logo]+Print Screen (I take a lot of screenshots)?

**EDIT:** I would really appreciate a free tool, as I don't want to get in trouble with the IT department:)
[image]

**UPDATE1:** it seems (as the AutoHotkey sees it) the 4 buttons are something like < launch calculator >, Delete, F9, Backspace... so I would need some advice on how to differentiate between the normal Delete/F9/Backspace keys (see the left side of the picture) and "special" keys (the ones above the numeric keys).

**UPDATE2:** I'd tried the following AutoHotkey code `Launch_App2::#PrintScreen` to get a 'WindowsLogo'+''PrintScreen' combination, but when you're right clicking the AutoHotkesy script's icon on the tray I'm not having the screenshot. I just want to let you know this, I'm not aware of any other corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done with [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Autohotkey is a automation scripting language for Windows that can, among other things, simulate or remap key presses.

Assuming those special keys (like calculator) send an actual key press Autohotkey can register, it can be remapped [using a well documented procedure](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Use a [keyboard hook to find the key codes](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys in the past to remap/turn off the Caps Lock key. Maybe give it a try?

License-wise a commercial use is fine (Microsoft Public License), though you will need admin rights to run it.